# Getting "No module named pabot.__main__; 'pabot' is a package and cannot be directly executed" error, when I try to do parallel execution using pabot

Tags: python, robotframework

I have created a robot script and tried to run the scripts in parallel using "pabot" package. Im getting the below error message stating that no **main**.py in the installed package.

**Steps that I followed which cause this error.**

1. Installed pabaot using the below cmd:

   ```
   pip install robotframework-pabot
   ```
2. Below is the command I used to execute scripts using pabot

   ```
   C:\Users\Prakash\PycharmProjects\Prakash_RobotFramework\tests>python -m pabot .
   ```
3. Below is the error message I received while executing the cmd.

   > C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe: No module named pabot.**main**; 'pabot' is a package and cannot be directly executed"
4. I have checked the pabot installed folder where **main**.py is not available.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try reading the [documentation](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot#basic-use) for what you installed? How does it say that you should run the code? Did you try doing that? Please read [ask] and keep in mind that this is not a tech support site; we cannot help you with simply using someone else's program - we can only help you if the problem involves writing code yourself. Please also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592.

Comment: According to the documentation, the command to use is `paybot` rather than `python -m pabot`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    pabot.pabotLib
```

Execution:

Split execution to suite files»

**pabot --pabotlib [path to tests]**

Split execution on test level»

**pabot --pabotlib --testlevelsplit [path to tests]**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a pabot and pabotlib class within pabot. Use the following command to call pabot class within the pabot module.

```
python -m pabot.pabot --testlevelsplit .
```